# Changed accepted answer, and then the user deleted the one I originally accepted

Tags: discussion

I asked the question [Why does ReSharper tell me “implicitly captured closure”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633617/why-does-resharper-tell-me-implicitly-captured-closure) ages ago. I initially accepted an answer, because it's explanation was the best at the time. This answer went on to acquire quite a few upvotes (was at 50 last I'd checked). A few months ago, I had a notification about this question and when I read it, I noticed an answer with quite a few more upvotes, that was actually a great answer. Not to mention there were a LOT of comments suggesting that I change the accepted answer(am I obligated to change an accepted answer that came almost 6 months later after accepting an answer that was sufficient for me?) So, I changed the accepted answer, and I just noticed that the original accepted answer has been deleted. That answer, though not as succinct as the now accepted answer, was still a very valid answer to my question. So, my question is, should the user be allowed to delete an answer that had so many votes? Can we get that answer undeleted?

Comment: He only deleted it after you unaccepted it.  Possibly because there are comments on it saying it is answering the wrong question.

Comment: @Plutonix: I know. Was that not clear in my question?

Comment: There are multiple comments in the vein of "This is not the correct answer", one of which is upvoted 28 times.  The answer was also downvoted 28 times.  I know nothing about the subject, but at least part of the community felt that it *wasn't* a valid answer to your question, and the poster followed that advice.  Why undelete it?

Comment: You're not able to delete your own answer when it's accepted, so he was probably waiting on you to unaccept it before he could delete it.

Answer (score 7):

> am I obligated to change an accepted answer that came almost 6 months later after accepting an answer that was sufficient for me?

No.

You have no obligation to change your accepted answer or even accept an answer at all. It's totally your decision and it's of no concern to anyone else. Comments asking you to accept or change your accepted answer should be flagged for removal. Having said that if you think a different answer is now a better answer then you can change your acceptance.

As for whether the user can delete their answer - of course they can. Given that it was older than 60 days and at a score of 3+ they even get to keep the reputation earned. The moderators wouldn't normally undelete an answer deleted by the author, unless it was part of a "rage quit", in which case we would act.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that an answer has a lot of votes doesn't, and shouldn't prevent the author from deleting it.  In the event that the content was actually valuable content, and the user was intentionally vandalizing his own content by deleting posts that he knew were good, there are things that could be done, and tools in place to prevent/mitigate such vandalism.

In this case though, there is no vandalism.  The answer was wrong, and the author was simply unable to delete the answer after noticing their mistake until you unaccepted it.  While a mod, or the community, *could* undelete it if the content was valuable, it *isn't*, so we *shouldn't*.

The fact that the answer *seems* to answer the question, and appear, at first glance, to be the answer, even though it is not, make it all the more problematic, and the reason why the site is better off with it being deleted.